# Error when downloading CMIP6 climate change data in NetCDF format with pyesgf.search

Tags: python, netcdf, request

I am trying to download NetCDF files, which contain daily maximum and minimum temperature precipitation data with a historical timeline from 1850 to 2014 and projected into the future for 2015 to 2100 (CMIP6), for this I am using the pyesgf.search python package in miniconda, this is based on this [book](https://claut.gitlab.io/man_ccia/lab2.html#data-search) . When I run the code everything works fine but when downloading the netCDF files, I get an error that I don't know what it is due to, I attach the code used:

```
# Importar librerías
from pyesgf.search import SearchConnection 
import os # Crear y manipular archivos y directorios
import pandas as pd # manipulación y análisis de datos
import requests # permite realizar solicitudes HTTP de forma sencilla y eficiente. 
from tqdm import tqdm 
os.environ["ESGF_PYCLIENT_NO_FACETS_STAR_WARNING"] = "on"

# Configura la conexión con ESGF
conn = SearchConnection('https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/esg-search', distrib=True)

# Define los parámetros de búsqueda para el experimento histórico, Source ID CanESM5
query = conn.new_context(
    latest = True,
    project='CMIP6',
    source_id='CanESM5',
    experiment_id='historical,ssp119,ssp126,ssp245,ssp370,ssp585',
   # experiment_id= "historical",
   # variable_id='tas,tasmax,tasmin,pr',
    variable_id='tasmax,tasmin,pr',
    table_id="day",
    member_id='r1i1p1f1',
    data_node='crd-esgf-drc.ec.gc.ca')

# Ejecutar la busqueda y visualizar el tamaño
results = query.search()
len(results)

# "lambda", para extraer el nombre del archivo y la URL de cada resultado.
files = map(lambda f : {'filename': f.filename, 'url': f.download_url}, hit)

# Convertirlo a lista
files = list(files)
files

# Agrupar esto en una sola llamada.
files_2 = list(map(lambda f: {"filename": f.filename, "url": f.download_url}, 
              results[1].file_context().search()))
files_2
files.extend(files_2)
for i in range(2, len(results)):
    files.extend(list(map(lambda f : {'filename': f.filename, 'url': f.download_url},
                               results[i].file_context().search())))
# Conversión a data frame
files = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(files)
files

# Función para descarga de archivos adaptado de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37573701
def download(url, filename):
    print("Downloading ", filename)
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    total_size, block_size = int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0)), 1024
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        for data in tqdm(r.iter_content(block_size),
                         total=total_size//block_size,
                         unit='KiB', unit_scale=True):
            f.write(data)

    if total_size != 0 and os.path.getsize(filename) != total_size:
        print("Downloaded size does not match expected size!\n",
              "FYI, the status code was ", r.status_code)

# Descar todos los archivos.
for index, row in files.iterrows():
    if os.path.isfile(row.filename):
        print("File exists. Skipping.")
    else:
        download(row.url, row.filename)
```

When I run the code it starts downloading the data but I get an error that I don't know why, as I show in the following images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The error generated is this: requests ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(13106844 bytes read, 14220560 more expected)'

Has someone gone through this and solved it?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question so the error message is in the body of the Question as text.

Comment: Vince Thanks for the corrections, they are ready.